# Functionality performed on scipy class

Tags: python, scipy

I am using 1d interpolation with interp1d from Scipy. the below code I am using,

```
Hest_abs = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(pilotCarriers, abs(Hest_at_pilots), kind='linear')(allCarriers)
```

as I see in the class declaration of "1d interpolation with interp1d" this is how it should be done:

```
class scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='linear', axis=-1, copy=True, bounds_error=None, fill_value=nan, assume_sorted=False)
```

My query is what the operation performed with the (allCarriers) in the above code? As I am new to python any help will be useful.

Comment: If the (allCarriers) is multiplied by the value of class scipy.interpolate.interp1d? if its multiplication then asterisk symbol isn't there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html

```
class scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='linear', axis=-1, copy=True, bounds_error=None, fill_value=nan, assume_sorted=False)[source]
Interpolate a 1-D function.

x and y are arrays of values used to approximate some function 
f: y = f(x). This class returns a function whose call method uses 
interpolation to find the value of new points.

Methods

__call__(self, x)

Evaluate the interpolant
```

So

```
X = scipy.interpolate.interp1d(pilotCarriers, abs(Hest_at_pilots), kind='linear')
```

creates an object that is `callable`, i.e. can be used as function:

```
Hest_abs = X(allCarriers)
```